# Python Shell Erro

Tags: python

I have been using this code in a python shell- version 2.7.3, and I am getting this error. The code seems okay and I don't understand where I am going wrong.

This is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Python27\problem8euler.py", line 25, in <module>
        num.append(int(char))
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Here is my code:

```
string = # that really long number, edited out for page-width-sanity 

num = [] 

for char in string: 
    num.append(int(char)) 


answers = [] 


i = 0 

while i <= len(num) - 5: 
    k = i + 1 
    l = i + 2 
    m = i + 3 
    n = i + 4 
    prod = ( num[i] * num[k] * num[l] * num[m] * num[n]) 
    answers.append(prod) 
    i += 1 

print max(answers)
```

The code is my solution for Project Euler problem 8.

Comments will be appreciated on where I am going wrong.

Comment: Please don't edit out the number; it's vitally important for this error message (in fact, everything after the fourth line can be safely deleted). If you want to create a smaller example: thank you! [But make sure to make it complete, reproducible and correct](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Is 25 your last line  (`print max(answers)`)?

Comment: It looks like you may have a typo in the long number.  Perhaps you forgot to remove a quote mark or a space or something?

Answer (score 1):

`string` contains a space character. You call `int` on every character in `string`, and `int(' ')` fails:

```
>>> int(' ')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

Simply remove the space character to fix the problem, or skip spaces in `string`, like this:

```
string = '1 2'
num = [int(c) for c in string if not c.isspace()]
```

(The `[.. for ..]` construct is called a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions).)

Comment: The quotes around the traceback threw me for a loop.  I was trying to figure out what could possibly be in the string for it to print `'' '`.  (really it just printed `' '` I suppose.)